# NoneType on webscraper code

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I'm trying to build a simple web scraper (new python programmer here - please forgive simple questions).
Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

comments_url = 'https://somewebsite.com'

comments_page = urllib2.urlopen(comments_url)

raw_data = BeautifulSoup(comments_page, 'html.parser')
data = raw_data.find('tr',attrs={'data-ix-row': 'data-ix-bug'})
print(type(data))`
```

For reference, here are the classes I'm trying to parse out of the webpage: 
[html_grab_reference page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Prl.jpg)

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
<type 'NoneType'>
```

I made a mistake somewhere along the data I queried (I think) and it's returning nothing.
Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: Because beautifulsoup didn't find what you were looking for

Comment: If your website is generated by Javascript, you can't use just urllib2 and beautifulsoup to parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting None because it wasn't found. Your attributes are not assigned to each other. You have a class, and a regular attribute.

Plus, the attribute looks like a generated number (probably by Javascript, so urllib2 won't render it to the HTML)

If it does work, you'll need at least this

```
attrs={'class': 'data-ix-row'}
```

And then filter out the `data-ix-bug` for whatever value you're interested in. (And you'll want to `find_all`, probably)

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, I presume that in your example, I can use 'attrs' as a dictionary and have multiple JS classes called ?

Comment: This answers the question as it seems indeed that I need a module that is able to parse javascript code that might be generated in that page.

Comment: Selenium webdriver is a popular choice. There's others to parse "dynamic web pages"

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a try with Selenium and Chrome webdriver.